# Measuring typical seperation between patches using 2D Fourier Transform

Tags: fft, correlation, distance-metrics

I need to extract information about the typical distance between the black patches in an image like the one I attached here. Typical distance would be the the most frequent separation between two patches. For example, if the photo was parallel black stripes, the algorithm would give me the typical width of the white stripes between the black stripes.

I tried to perform 2D FFT on it (using OpenCF fdt function in Python), but I am not sure if this is the best way to do this job. Anyone has an idea what is the method that I need to use to perform this job? I have read about two-point correlation function in astronomy, but I wonder if it can be used also in this case..

This is an example of the image on which I need to do this analysis - [image: black patches]